# Extract everything after 2nd last / in a string in microsoft excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a bunch of URLs with different lengths and folder paths. I wish to extract everything after the 2nd last / in them.

The example URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/path-name-here/12345678/
https://www.example.com/folder1/folder2/path-name-here/39089/
```

The output should be:

```
12345678
39089
```

I have tried a bunch of different functions but no luck so far so would appreciate if someone can support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1,"/",-2),"/")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 365 you can use this formula:

```
=TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"/",,TRUE),,-1)
```

It first splits the whole string into its parts giving back the last one (= -1 in `TAKE`-formula)

Comment: This is a good one

Answer (score 0):

If you need it to work on other versions too:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",1000)),2000))
```